# SQL Query calculating the average of an average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I read through several posts on similar issues to this, and cannot seem to find the correct solution. I have tried adding the calculation to several parts of the query, without success. I am sure I am missing something simple.

I work at a mine and I was asked to accomplish the following:

They want to know which trucks was more than 5 % below the average payload of all the other trucks average payload over the past 3 days. It also needs to exclude any trucks that had less than 10 loads

There are 3 tables:

1. hist_loads (Gives payload and a lot of other information)
2. hist_exproot (Gives information related to dates, need this to give
   a readable date)
3. hist_eqmtlist (Need this to determine the specific truck models, as
   not all truck models must be included)

All of the above tables are joined together by a column called "shiftindex")

Below is my Query:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#pave') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#pave;
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#pfinal') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#pfinal;

select  
    shiftdate
    ,truck
    ,AVG(measureton) as measureton
    ,COUNT(excav) as loads
into #pfinal
from hist_loads as hl
inner join hist_exproot as he on 
he.shiftindex = hl.shiftindex 
inner join hist_eqmtlist as heq on
heq.shiftindex = hl.shiftindex and 
hl.truck = heq.eqmtid
where hl.shiftindex between 
                            (select min(shiftindex) 
                            from hist_exproot 
                            where datepart(year,shiftdate) = datepart(year, getdate()-3)
                            and datepart(month,shiftdate) = datepart(month, getdate()-3)
                            and datepart(day,shiftdate) = datepart(day, getdate()-3))
        and 
                            (select max(shiftindex) 
                            from hist_exproot 
                            where datepart(year,shiftdate) = datepart(year, getdate()-1)
                            and datepart(month,shiftdate) = datepart(month, getdate()-1)
                            and datepart(day,shiftdate) = datepart(day, getdate()-1)) 

and eqmttype in ('Euclid EH4500','Euclid EH4500-W','Euclid EH4500-HW')
and expit like 1
and measureton not like 0

group by eqmttype, truck, shiftdate
having COUNT(excav) > 10

select  
    shiftdate
    ,AVG(measureton) as measureton
    ,COUNT(excav) as loads
into #pave
from hist_loads as hl
inner join hist_exproot as he on 
he.shiftindex = hl.shiftindex 
inner join hist_eqmtlist as heq on
heq.shiftindex = hl.shiftindex and 
hl.truck = heq.eqmtid
where hl.shiftindex between 
                            (select min(shiftindex) 
                            from hist_exproot 
                            where datepart(year,shiftdate) = datepart(year, getdate()-3)
                            and datepart(month,shiftdate) = datepart(month, getdate()-3)
                            and datepart(day,shiftdate) = datepart(day, getdate()-3))
        and 
                            (select max(shiftindex) 
                            from hist_exproot 
                            where datepart(year,shiftdate) = datepart(year, getdate()-1)
                            and datepart(month,shiftdate) = datepart(month, getdate()-1)
                            and datepart(day,shiftdate) = datepart(day, getdate()-1)) 

and eqmttype in ('Euclid EH4500','Euclid EH4500-W','Euclid EH4500-HW')
and measureton not like 0

group by eqmttype, shiftdate
having COUNT(excav) > 10

select ave.shiftdate, ave.measureton, final.truck
from #pave as ave
left join #pfinal as final on 
ave.shiftdate = final.shiftdate
where final.measureton < ave.measureton
order by truck
```

My Result:

```
shiftdate           measureton         truck
2017-12-03 00:00:00 230.444365964912    DT01
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT04
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT07
2017-12-03 00:00:00 230.444365964912    DT07
2017-12-04 00:00:00 226.141955641026    DT07
2017-12-04 00:00:00 226.141955641026    DT10
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT13
2017-12-03 00:00:00 230.444365964912    DT14
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT15
2017-12-03 00:00:00 230.444365964912    DT17
2017-12-04 00:00:00 226.141955641026    DT17
2017-12-03 00:00:00 230.444365964912    DT20
2017-12-04 00:00:00 226.141955641026    DT20
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT22
2017-12-04 00:00:00 226.141955641026    DT24
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT25
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT27
2017-12-03 00:00:00 230.444365964912    DT27
2017-12-04 00:00:00 226.141955641026    DT28
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT30
2017-12-02 00:00:00 231.123014419048    DT31
2017-12-03 00:00:00 230.444365964912    DT31
2017-12-04 00:00:00 226.141955641026    DT32
```

But I only need the trucks that were more than 5% under the average payload. The above result seems to be all of the trucks average payload over the past 3 days. And there also seem to be some repetition between 3 numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want an average payload by truck type?

Comment: @Diacide: What do you mean by "under the average payload"? Is it the average payload within a day? the average payload for a truck? The average payload for all trucks in the last 3 days?

Comment: Basically: Average payload of all trucks over 3 days, Then check which of those trucks are 5% under that average. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So the math would go: SUM(All payloads over 3 days)/number of loads = Average

Then: Check all trucks that's average is: < (Average - 5%)

Comment: And it does not have to be by truck type. I only use the truck types to filter for specific trucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were pretty close... Can't confirm without your actual data, but lets see if this simplified query will work for you...

The first query, I have pre-computed just gathers data based on the date-only field without having to break down the year/month/day individually.

GetDate() by itself will return the current date AND time.  To get just the date, I am running CONVERT(date, getdate()), so 2017-12-05 08:22:15 am is stripped to just 2017-12-05.  Also, by doing dateadd() -3 days will bring this down to 2017-12-02.  The where clause is now >= '2017-12-02' AND LESS than '2017-12-05' which is inclusive of '2017-12-04 at 11:59:59 pm' getting the ENTIRE 12-04 day covering your entire 3 days requested.

You originally had the count > 10 but said to discard any that had LESS than 10 trips, so I changed to >= 10.  Your other criteria left as-is.

So at the end of this first query into the temp table give only the activity for the 3 days in question for the trucks qualified and gets the average per each truck.

```
SELECT
      shiftdate,
      truck,
      AVG(measureton) as measureton,
      COUNT(excav) as loads
   into 
      #pTruckAvgs
   from
      hist_loads as hl
         inner join hist_exproot as he 
            ON hl.shiftindex = he.shiftindex
         inner join hist_eqmtlist as heq 
            ON hl.shiftindex = heq.shiftindex 
            and hl.truck = heq.eqmtid
   where 
          hl.shiftindex >= DateAdd( day, -3, CONVERT(date, getdate()) )
      and hl.shiftindex < CONVERT(date, getdate())
      and eqmttype in ('Euclid EH4500','Euclid EH4500-W','Euclid EH4500-HW')
      and expit like 1
      and measureton not like 0
   group by 
      eqmttype, 
      truck, 
      shiftdate
   having 
      COUNT(excav) >= 10;
```

Now, you have a temp table of all trucks and their respective averages.  You don't need to requery again based on the dates and such, just grab the averages from this temp table ( via the QualAvgs result alias).  Here, you were looking for 5% less than the average, so I am taking the average * .95 and getting all truck averages that were LESS than the 95% of all averages.  Drop the temp table when finished.

```
select
      TA.*,
      QualAvgs.AllAvg
    from
       #pTruckAvgs TA,
       ( select AVG(measureton) as AllAvg
            from #pTruckAvgs ) QualAvgs
    where
       TA.measureTon < ( QualAvgs.AllAvg * .95);


drop table #pTruckAvgs;
```

Now final thought... For the average on a per-day-basis might need a slight shift... For example, if bad weather, or other unforeseen restrictions making every truck slow on a single day, you might want.

```
select
      TA.*,
      QualAvgs.AllAvg
    from
       #pTruckAvgs TA,
       ( select shiftdate,
                 AVG(measureton) as AllAvg
            from #pTruckAvgs 
            group by shiftdate ) QualAvgs
    where
           TA.measureTon < ( QualAvgs.AllAvg * .95)
       AND TA.ShiftDate = QualAvgs.ShiftDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without an testable and verifiable example but I managed to do it:

```
drop table hist_loads
drop table hist_exproot
drop table hist_eqmtlist

GO
create table hist_loads
(
  shiftindex int,
  truck int,
  measureton decimal(18,2),
    --,AVG(measureton) as measureton
    --,COUNT(excav) as loads
   excav int
)


create table hist_exproot
(
  shiftindex int,
  shiftdate date,
)

create table hist_eqmtlist
(
   shiftindex int,
   eqmtid int, -- hl.truck = heq.eqmtid
   eqmttype varchar(100) --in ('Euclid EH4500','Euclid EH4500-W','Euclid EH4500-HW')
)
GO

insert into hist_loads values
 (1,1,100,1)
,(2,1,200,1)
,(3,1,300,1)
,(4,1,100,1)
,(5,1,200,1)
,(6,1,300,1)
,(7,1,100,1)
,(8,1,200,1)
,(9,1,300,1)
,(10,1,100,1)
,(11,1,200,1)
,(12,1,300,1)

,(13,2,300,1)
,(14,2,295,1)
,(15,2,295,1)
,(16,2,300,1)
,(17,2,295,1)
,(18,2,295,1)
,(19,2,300,1)
,(20,2,295,1)
,(21,2,295,1)
,(22,2,300,1)
,(23,2,295,1)
,(24,2,295,1)
,(25,2,300,1)
,(26,2,295,1)
,(27,2,295,1)

,(28,3,300,1)
,(29,3,300,1)
,(30,3,300,1)
,(31,3,300,1)
,(32,3,300,1)
,(33,3,300,1)
,(34,3,300,1)
,(35,3,300,1)
,(36,3,300,1)
,(37,3,300,1)
,(38,3,300,1)
,(39,3,300,1)
,(40,3,300,1)
,(41,3,300,1)
,(42,3,300,1)

,(43,4,999,1)

insert into hist_exproot values
 (1,'2017-12-05')
,(2,'2017-12-05')
,(3,'2017-12-05')
,(4,'2017-12-05')
,(5,'2017-12-05')
,(6,'2017-12-05')
,(7,'2017-12-05')
,(8,'2017-12-05')
,(9,'2017-12-05')
,(10,'2017-12-05')
,(11,'2017-12-05')
,(12,'2017-12-05')
,(13,'2017-12-05')
,(14,'2017-12-05')
,(15,'2017-12-05')
,(16,'2017-12-05')
,(17,'2017-12-05')
,(18,'2017-12-05')
,(19,'2017-12-05')
,(20,'2017-12-05')
,(21,'2017-12-05')
,(22,'2017-12-05')
,(23,'2017-12-05')
,(24,'2017-12-05')
,(25,'2017-12-05')
,(26,'2017-12-05')
,(27,'2017-12-05')
,(28,'2017-12-05')
,(29,'2017-12-05')
,(30,'2017-12-05')
,(31,'2017-12-05')
,(32,'2017-12-05')
,(33,'2017-12-05')
,(34,'2017-12-05')
,(35,'2017-12-05')
,(36,'2017-12-05')
,(37,'2017-12-05')
,(38,'2017-12-05')
,(39,'2017-12-05')
,(40,'2017-12-05')
,(41,'2017-12-05')
,(42,'2017-12-05')
,(43,'2017-12-05')

insert into hist_eqmtlist values
 (1,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(2,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(3,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(4,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(5,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(6,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(7,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(8,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(9,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(10,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(11,1,'Euclid EH4500')
,(12,1,'Euclid EH4500')

,(13,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(14,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(15,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(16,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(17,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(18,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(19,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(20,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(21,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(22,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(23,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(24,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(25,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(26,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')
,(27,2,'Euclid EH4500-W')

,(28,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(29,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(30,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(31,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(32,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(33,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(34,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(35,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(36,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(37,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(38,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(39,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(40,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(41,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')
,(42,3,'Euclid EH4500-HW')

,(43,4,'Euclid EH4500-HW')

GO

declare @dateIni date, @dateEnd date = getdate()
set @dateIni =  dateadd(day,-3,@dateEnd)



select *
into #temp_loads
from
(
    select
     hl.truck
    ,AVG(hl.measureton) as avg_measureton
    ,COUNT(hl.excav) as loads
    from hist_loads hl
    join hist_exproot hex on hex.shiftindex = hl.shiftindex
    where
    hex.shiftdate between @dateIni and @dateEnd
    and exists (select * from hist_eqmtlist heq where heq.eqmtid = hl.truck and heq.eqmttype in ('Euclid EH4500','Euclid EH4500-W','Euclid EH4500-HW')) -- not a join because cannot be sure of the table correlation and data sanity
    group by hl.truck
) as ld
where ld.loads >= 10

declare @average_measureton decimal = (select AVG(avg_measureton) from #temp_loads)
declare @treshould decimal = @average_measureton -(@average_measureton/20.0)

select @average_measureton, @treshould

select tl.truck, tl.avg_measureton, hex.shiftdate
from #temp_loads tl
join hist_eqmtlist heq on heq.eqmtid = tl.truck
join hist_exproot hex on hex.shiftindex = heq.shiftindex
where tl.avg_measureton > @treshould
and hex.shiftdate between @dateIni and @dateEnd
-- you can repeat the truck type test here but it's not necessary, lef tit at the aggregation for performance

drop table #temp_loads
```

It's a simple case of getting the average and storing it in a variable to be used in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But it gives me all loads that were 5% below the average. What needs to be checked after that is done, is to get an average per truck, over the same period, then check if the average of each individual truck is 5% below the average of all the trucks. Then only return the ones that's average is 5% below that.

Comment: @Diacide Added date restriction on the aggregate so only the average over the period will be calculated

Answer (score 0):

@DRapp. Thanks, this worked, with a bit of a tweak. Your date logic gave me some errors in SSMS. So I replaced it with my date logic:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

I also removed the shiftdate in the select statement, as I realized it was not a requirement to split it into seperate dates. On a request, I also extended the timeframe to 7 days. So the final working query looks as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#pTruckAvgs') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#pTruckAvgs;

SELECT
      truck,
      AVG(measureton) as measureton,
      COUNT(excav) as loads
   into 
      #pTruckAvgs
   from
      hist_loads as hl
         inner join hist_exproot as he 
            ON hl.shiftindex = he.shiftindex
         inner join hist_eqmtlist as heq 
            ON hl.shiftindex = heq.shiftindex 
            and hl.truck = heq.eqmtid
   where 
          hl.shiftindex between 
                            (select min(shiftindex) 
                            from hist_exproot 
                            where datepart(year,shiftdate) = datepart(year, getdate()-7)
                            and datepart(month,shiftdate) = datepart(month, getdate()-7)
                            and datepart(day,shiftdate) = datepart(day, getdate()-7))
        and 
                            (select max(shiftindex) 
                            from hist_exproot 
                            where datepart(year,shiftdate) = datepart(year, getdate()-1)
                            and datepart(month,shiftdate) = datepart(month, getdate()-1)
                            and datepart(day,shiftdate) = datepart(day, getdate()-1)) 
      --and hl.shiftindex < CONVERT(date, getdate())
      and eqmttype in ('Euclid EH4500','Euclid EH4500-W','Euclid EH4500-HW')
      and expit like 1
      and measureton not like 0
      and measureton > 150
   group by 
      eqmttype, 
      truck
   having 
      COUNT(excav) >= 10;

select
      TA.*,
      QualAvgs.AllAvg
    from
       #pTruckAvgs TA,
       (select AVG(measureton) as AllAvg
            from #pTruckAvgs ) QualAvgs
    where
       TA.measureTon < ( QualAvgs.AllAvg * .95);
```

The result looks as follows:

```
truck   measureton          loads   AllAvg
DT05    204.876060232558    43      224.850465129605
```

Thanks for everyone's assistance, it is highly appreciated.